# How create popup menu item in PackageExplorer only for directories

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing Eclispe (Kepler) plugin. Main goal of this plugin is to add in PackageExplorer popup menu "Open In Explorer" item. This item should be visible for directories,packages etc. but no for files. I've tried this:

```
<menuContribution
    locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
    <command
          commandId="pl.com.tt.wide.lms.core.commands.sampleCommand"
          id="pl.com.tt.wide.lms.core.menus.sampleCommand"
          mnemonic="S">
        <visibleWhen>
               <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
                <iterate
                     ifEmpty="false">
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                        <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.type" value="org.eclipse.core.resources.FOLDER"/>
                    </adapt>
                </iterate>
               </with>
        </visibleWhen>
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```

This is not working. Do you have any suggestions how to accomplish this? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem right now. I tried using `adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer` and `IFolder` with no success. My searches haven't lead to any solution up until now. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think, first of all the idea is not to hide elements of a Menu, rather disable them. This gives users at least the hint, that there will be a command available, but not just now. So I'd use "enableWhen" instead of "visibleWhen".
 Otherwise you have weirdly changing menus and orders of items depending on selection, which might increase the confusion. Especially within Eclipse, where you are surrounded by confusion. :-)

Maybe take a look at the this already existing plug-in: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell#.Ul6fNfnIZsg

Answer (score 0):

The Package Explorer does not only use types of `org.eclipse.core.resources` but uses the types of `org.ecliplse.jdt.core`, too.

Have a look at `IPackageFragment`, `IPackageFragmentRoot` and `IJavaProject`. Using these in an `or` statement will probably produce, what you want.

This is what worked for me:

```
<visibleWhen>
   <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
      <iterate ifEmpty="false">
         <or>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject">
            </adapt>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragmentRoot">
            </adapt>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment">
            </adapt>
         </or>
      </iterate>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
```