# popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer not visible for Java projects

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse to help me with some custom errors and warnings. Started by creating a new plugin project using the wizard, chose the option with the nature and markers in it.

This automatically added a menu item in the project's context menu (popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?after=additions)

This seemed to work for most projects. Except the projects i needed it for. The menu item simply does not show up for Java projects in the Package Explorer.

I only changed the default ?after to be ?before, so the menu-item is in a location that suited me better (for the projects that it does work on).

[Screenshot if what i've got now](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1088i00&s=8)
That shows it's working on a non-java project in the Package Explorer.

I also added the same menu-item to the Project Explorer, all works fine there.

[Here is a link to the plugin.xml i currently have.](http://pastebin.com/vm5KXx0L)

The project it DOES NOT work on, is a simple java project freshly generated from the Eclipse "New -> Java Project" wizard. Any other java project doesn't work either.

The project it DOES work on, is freshly generated from the "Plug-in Development -> Update Site Project" wizard.

#### Stuff i tried:

I know it is not the same as [popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709650/popuporg-eclipse-jdt-ui-packageexplorer-not-visible), i'm adding the menu-item to the context menu of a project, not files or directories.
However, i did try using:

```
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
  <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.contentTypeId" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject" />
</adapt>
```

instead of the `<instanceof>` tags, which also did not work. in fact, removing the whole `<instanceof>` tag does not even work.

I know it is not the same as [Eclipse plugin menu item is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524270/eclipse-plugin-menu-item-is-not-visible), the generated plugin.xml used `selection`, which i later changed to `activeMenuSelection` because that matched the documentation, and what the Plug-in Selection Spy says it actually is. Again, no change.

I think it is not the same as [How create popup menu item in PackageExplorer only for directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359209/how-create-popup-menu-item-in-packageexplorer-only-for-directories), but i did try to use the suggested code and toyed around with it, no luck.

So, to summarize:

This is my first Eclipse plugin, most of the GUI stuff is generated from the Plug-in Developent wizard. Now i hope a real wizard can lead me to the answers i seek.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the "visible when" option for you `com.mycompany.converterhelper.addRemoveJavaFileNature` in the plugin.xml? Does your command appear in the PackageExplorer without that option?

Comment: Completely removing the `<visibleWhen>` tag does show the menu-item. But i want to show it only on the Java projects.

Comment: this wasn't thought as a solution, but to narrow down the range of possible causes. It seems to me your code does what you told it to do. enabled=false is set, when you have a Project that does not have the "com.mycompany.converterhelper.javaFileNature" nature AND does have the "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature" nature. So all Java projects without the "com.mycompany.converterhelper.javaFileNature" will have the Command removed from their popup.

Comment: I think i read your response about 50 times now, and i still don't understand...

I add two menu-items to the same menu, a "Enable" and a "Disable" option, which should be mutual exclusive. But for every Java project, one of them should be visible (which it currently isn't).

Comment: Sorry, the comment section isn't exactly great for code answers and my breaks are short ^^. I'll try to write it up nicely this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<adapt>` tag gave me an idea to adapt the project to an IResource. Then check for natures from inside the `<adapt>` tag. And that seemed to work!

The [Platform Expression Framework](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Expression_Framework) page at eclipse.org also helped me understand what each of the tags exactly do.

So, i think my problem was actually similar to the one i linked first ([popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709650/popuporg-eclipse-jdt-ui-packageexplorer-not-visible)). Feel pretty dumb about that now...

Relevant part of my current plugin.xml:

```
    <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
      <with variable="activeMenuSelection">
        <count value="1" />
        <iterate operator="and">
          <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <and>
              <not>
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" value="com.mycompany.converterhelper.javaFileNature" />
              </not>
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature" />
            </and>
          </adapt>
        </iterate>
      </with>
    </visibleWhen>
```

[And a link to the entire plugin.xml](http://pastebin.com/YnGg8uWL)

I want to thank Calon for his time and effort :-)